# ruby version is not installing <= 2.2.5 or 2.2.0

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I'm having trouble installing ruby 2.2.0 on my Linux system using rvm as my ruby version manager:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: kali/kali-rolling/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.0 - #downloading ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.6M  100 12.6M    0     0   9223      0  0:24:02  0:24:02 --:--:--  8338
ruby-2.2.0 - #extracting ruby-2.2.0 to /root/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0.....
ruby-2.2.0 - #applying patch /root/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.0 - #applying patch /root/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/openssl3.patch.
ruby-2.2.0 - #configuring.........................................................
ruby-2.2.0 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.2.0 - #compiling..............................................................................................................................................................................-
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /root/.rvm/log/1612011949_ruby-2.2.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Have you thought of reading `/root/.rvm/log/1612011949_ruby-2.2.0/make.log` ?

Comment: i don'd know much about that but while i installed any ruby version above 2.4.x something then it's work fine but while i try to install less then 2.3.x or 2.2.x etc its raising an errors as like i posted above.

Comment: can you edit the question and include the contents of the `/root/.rvm/log/1612011949_ruby-2.2.0/make.log` file?  as an aside: why are you using rvm as root?  surely you're better off using it without sudo?